# Prove that $\overline{X} =X\cup X'$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(M,d)$ metric space and $X\subset M$. Then $\overline{X} =X\cup X'$.

I need help proving that $\overline{X} \subseteq X\cup X'$. I don't have any idea to do this part. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x\notin X\cup X'$. Then, there exists some open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U\cap X=\varnothing$. So, $X\subset U^c$, which means that $\bar X\subset U^c$ (since $U^c$ is closed), which implies $x\notin \bar X$.